# Not able to build ReactiveCocoa

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

I am building a project which I got from another developer. While building ReactiveCocoa it gives following error for multiple times. Tried online solution but none of them worked. Has anyone else faced this before?

```
While building module 'ReactiveCocoa' imported from Pods/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa.h:17:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Users/sankethpurwar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Heckscher-gzryniksoxyxjkdzbdonuizetozb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa.framework/Headers/ReactiveCocoa-umbrella.h:82:
In file included from /Users/sankethpurwar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Heckscher-gzryniksoxyxjkdzbdonuizetozb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa.framework/Headers/ReactiveCocoa.h:19:
Pods/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/NSArray+RACSequenceAdditions.h:13:21: error: duplicate definition of category 'RACSequenceAdditions' on interface 'NSArray'
@interface NSArray (RACSequenceAdditions)
```

Comment: What about cleaning project and deleting derived data?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha I tried cleaning the project. But that did not solve the problem.

Comment: did you try removing derived data? also there's one more thing which helped me once in a similar situation. I commented all the pods in Podfile, then ran pod install then uncommented everything and ran pod install again

Comment: @2ank3th which ReactiveCocoa version are using? What's your Swift compiler's version (`xcrun swift -version`)?